# Create service similar to wordpress.com

Tags: multisite, forms, wordpress.com-hosting, signup

I am looking to build a service for users where they can signup (using an online form such as Gravity or Ninja forms) for a website either as a sub domain or sub directory of the main website similar to wordpress.com. I am using wordpress multisite, but I cannot find anything online on how to accomplish this. Is there a special plugin or script/scripts that I can run?

Comment: [Research here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multisite?sort=votes&pageSize=50) and try to bring specific questions, check the guide [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a separate form to create a register page.

Go to the network Dashboard » Network setting » Enable both sites and users can register, and you are ready to go.

Visitors now to your site can register a new site at this URL:

```
yoursitename.com/wp-signup.php
```

And for reference you can go through this source to get a bit more handy on WordPress Multisite:

- [WordPress Multisite Guide - WPMU.ORG](http://wpmu.org/wordpress-multisite-guide/)

Let me know if helps to solve your problem.